# Does VMware ESx server run a operation system of its own to manage the the hardware(like a host OS) inside of VMware ESx server

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

Does VMWare ESXi software run a host operating system in itself (bare metal hypervisor). I know that the vSphere client is used to manage the VM's created inside of the server but what about the management of other things inside of the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMWare's ESXi *is* a bare metal hypervisor and little more, it does have a *nix-like user interface that's switched off by default that allows for some very specific operations to be carried out but it's really got nothing directly to do with the running of guest VMs and can be ignored by most users.

In terms of creating and managing guest VMs there's a number of ways to do this including a number of CLI methods, the built-in web-based interface and also the more enterprise-oriented vCenter method too.

Can I suggest VMWare's 'vSphere Install, Manage and Configure' course as a great starter in these products.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance,but can you elaborate about the unix like interface which is switched off, so how is it used and for what purpose?

Comment: There's a range of things you can do with it but most or all of them are available via the client-based CLI's - in particular the PowerCLI is very powerful and there's lots of existing scripts out there available for free to help with these things. To be honest though you really do sound like you'd benefit from some training, vSphere isn't the easiest thing to just pick up and go.

Comment: Thank you, I would look into some training courses and deeper learning about this.

Comment: Leaving the marketing bs aside, any system capable of performing actions and interacting with hardware is an OS. It might be scaled down to the bare minimum, or even pulled out into a secondary OS, like Xen's Dom0, but it's still an OS